# How to differentiate Layout on the basis of screenHeight?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support, android-layoutparams

I have a LinearLayout which I intend to fit within the screen bounds of 5' devices. Currently it is going out of bounds of the screen on 5' devices but stays within the limits of 5.2' inch devices.

I intend to use different values for dimensions for these 2 type of devices by creating a separate dimens.xml in values-730dp folder but 5.2' devices dont seem pick to pick these values. Both type of devices end up pick up the same value being defined in the values folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can do so by right clicking on res folder. Then click on Create new resource folder. Choose identifiers from below... In your case it is screen size. Then Put your layout file respectively.